# implement a form to display a set of forms, which have one or more fields the same

Tags: django, forms

everybody,

I have a table in database which is used to show the note for a student for a certain course.

- Student    Course    note
- Aaa  Math    A
- Bbb  English C

How can I show them in one form like:

- Student :  aaa
- Course:    math      note: a
- Course: english    note: a

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: Hi, I have try to do it with a studen modelform and a course model form and a student_course_note form(with out sutdent field and course filed) in one form....